# Remove key when reading json file

Tags: json

Try to read json file from another directory in React for `options` of react-select. It doesn't matter when writing json in the same file, but it doesn't work when reading from another file because it includes number of array.

```
1: {value: "America/New_York"name: "New York (Eastern)"}
2: {value: "America/Chicago", name: "Chicago(Central)"}
3: {value: "America/Denver", name: "Denver(Mountain)"}
4: {value: "America/Phoenix", name: "Phoenix (MST)"}
```

I want to remove number key.
Ideal case:

```
{ "value": "America/Puerto_Rico", "name": "Puerto Rico (Atlantic)" },
{ "value": "America/New_York", "name": "New York (Eastern)" },
{ "value": "America/Chicago", "name": "Chicago (Central)" },
{ "value": "America/Denver", "name": "Denver (Mountain)" }
```

The code:

timezone.json

```
[
  {value: "America/New_York", name: "New York (Eastern)"}, 
  {value: "America/Chicago", name: "Chicago (Central)"},
  {value: "America/Denver", name: "Denver (Mountain)"}
]
```

app.js

```js
import timezone from "./data/timezone";
console.log("timezzone", timezone);
```

Comment: Object.values(timezone)

Comment: Object.values(timezone) is not working. Same results...

Comment: are you transpiling your code with Babel or a similar tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the json file looks like something like this:

```
{
   1: {value: "America/New_York", name: "New York (Eastern)"},
   2: {value: "America/Chicago", name: "Chicago(Central)"},
   3: {value: "America/Denver", name: "Denver(Mountain)"},
   4: {value: "America/Phoenix", name: "Phoenix (MST)"},
}
```

You can simply convert it to an array:

```js
import timezone from "./data/timezone";
console.log(Object.values(timezone));
```

Object.values:

> The Object.values() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop. (The only difference is that a for...in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well.)

Comment: Thank you so much. I use json file `[{value: "America/New_York", name: "New York (Eastern)"}...` but after reading, it added number. So I want to read this at the same format before reading.

Comment: @k10a the JSON file looks invalid. all key and values should be wrapped in double quotations. Please first check your JSON against an online verifier: https://jsonlint.com/